# Generics and JSON

Tags: java, json, generics, playframework

I am using the Play framework.
I want to use the function renderJSON with 2 Objects as an argument. It doesn't seem to be possible so I am trying to create a class that contains the 2 objects. In order not to have to create a new class everytime, I want to use Generics but it doesn't seem to work:

Model :

```
public class JSONContainer<T> extends Model {

    private T myT;
    private StatusMessage mySm;

    public JSONContainer(T myT, StatusMessage mySm) {
        this.myT = myT;
        this.mySm = mySm;
    }
}
```

and then :

In a function of a Controller:

```
JSONContainer<User> myJ = new JSONContainer(logged,sm);
renderJSON(myJ);
```

where logged is a User, sm is a StatusMessage. I get the error:

```
type:   'play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException'
```

If I don't use Generics, it works fine. Any idea?

The console gives this output, where the line 43 is:

```
JSONContainer<User> myJ = new JSONContainer(logged,sm);
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see exactly which line throws the error?

Comment: I added more information

Comment: you have a nosuchmethod error, try a clean build (clear $play_home/tmp directory) and retry. btw, why does the JSON container need to extend Model ? shouldn't IMHO.

Comment: also, `JSONContainer<User> myJ = new JSONContainer(logged,sm);` should be written as `JSONContainer<User> myJ = new JSONContainer<User>(logged,sm);` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I finally used Collection, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a JSONContainer like I did, I think the best way is to go with Collection as shown in this user guide for GSON made by Google (the JSON mapper used by Play apparently) at http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples:

```
Collection collection = new ArrayList();
collection.add(logged); 
collection.add(sm);
renderJSON(collection);
```

Collection are good for serializing (Java object to JSON) but not good for deserializing (see the GSON user guide for more insight).

It is better, IMHO, to use Collection than JSONContainer as JSONContainer are not useful in that case and don't give more possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Generic entities can't be mapped by Hibernate.

You should do the generic class abstract and create specific implementations (using User and any other possible values of T). This should solve the issue

Comment: I used Collection instead, see my answer but it is nice to know that it is not possible.